# Access Dynamically Created Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user clicks on my link, the modal element is dynamically generated. I am trying to inject some code into the modal when it is created. My problem is that JavaScript cannot target my modal as it is dynamically generated. How would I do this?

I have tried using `on()` but I got the error that my modal cannot be found.

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-modal', function() {
  console.log( $('.my-modal') ); //cannot find .my-modal
}
```

Comment: *How* is your modal dynamically generated?  Please show that code.

Comment: It is generated by Bootstrap. It will take me sometime to find the code that creates the modal.

Comment: Can you include the upper-most modal container in your HTML and hide it first, then allow Bootstrap to fill that modal?

Comment: Use the show event on the modal, delegated from a parent element such as the document.

Comment: "cannot find .my-modal" What that means? $('.my-modal').length = 0?

Comment: Are you *sure* its dynamically created? The Bootstrap examples use pre made HTML for the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, f you are following the Bootstrap example then you may mean to use #my-modal (or #myModal if you follow them to the T) since they are identifying the modal by ID instead of class.

**EDIT:**
The bootstrap modals depend on some preformatted html so I'm not sure how yours is dynamically generated.